# Is there a method to get the fields of object if I know the ID?

Tags: soql

Hi I am using a SOQL query to return a list of Contact ids. These ids are strings.
Is there a way to use these ids to referece information on these contacts ids?

I think I need to use a sub query?

```
SELECT MyObject.Id, MyObject.name, MyObject.OtherContact, 
        (SELECT OtherContact.Name, MyObject.OtherContact.Telephone 
         FROM  MyObject.OtherContact 
         WHERE  OtherContact.Id = MyObject.OtherContact) 
FROM Object
```

Thanks
Barry

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether i understood your questions correctly. you can query the other fields of contact as you have list of contact ids:

Assumed that contact ids stored in a List **listOFContactIds**

`List<Contact> listOfContacts = [Select Id, Name, Email from Contact where Id in : listOfContactIds]`

Please refer this link for [More Info](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm)